# Android: Remove specific part of string that is inside a jsonObject, inside an arraylist

Tags: java, android, json

I have a class called GamesData that has strings and getters and setters for this strings.

I download strings from a json. One of these strings is an URL with an image. I download the images but on a small size, because of their URL. I need to download it on a bigger size. For this, I need to remove this "small" string from the URL:

```
"home_team_logo": "https:\/\/URL\/images\/teams\/small\/olympique-marseille-890.png"
```

I have more than one URL coming from a big json object, all inside a json array, formated like the one above.

This is what I do to get the json.

```
arrayList.add(new GamesData(
                                gamesDataObject.getString(TAG_DATE),
                                gamesDataObject.getString(TAG_COMPETITION),
                                gamesDataObject.getString(TAG_HOME_TEAM),
                                gamesDataObject.getString(TAG_AWAY_TEAM),
                                gamesDataObject.getString(TAG_ID)
                        ));
```

I need to remove from TAG_HOME_TEAM

```
    public static final String TAG_HOME_TEAM= "home_team_logo";
```

, which is that URL above, only the "small" part, so the image downloaded will be the full size one.

In fact I will need this for all 3 tags: TAG_COMPETITION, TAG_HOME_TEAM, TAG_AWAY_TEAM.

How on earth do I do this? xD

Comment: `gamesDataObject.getString(TAG_HOME_TEAM).replace("/small", "")`

Comment: This is what Androis Studio gave me back: ibb.co/iHEKbF

Comment: you don't need to escape `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking something like this might work:

```
gamesDataObject.getString(TAG_HOME_TEAM).replaceAll("\/small\/","/");
```

This uses a regular expression to match all occurrences of the patern. A simplepr less error prone approach may be to use

```
gamesDataObject.getString(TAG_HOME_TEAM).replace("\/small\/","/");
```

Which should only replace the first occurrence.

Comment: Yeah sorry about the extra /, I was coding sans IDE.

Comment: Absolutely, yes Pavneet has a similar and valid answer. I was merely typing and Googling the Javadocs for the correct method call. Didn't mean to plagiarize!

Comment: Actually I realize that you would have to double the escape charaters in my original example gamesDataObject.getString(TAG_HOME_TEAM).replaceAll("\\/small\\/","/");

Answer (score 2):

You can use `replace` , use `/small/` with `/` as replacement to avoid matching something like `/othersmallteamname/`

```
       String s = "https:/URL/images/teams/small/olympique-marseille-890.png";
       System.out.println(s.replace("/small/", "/"));
```

Output :

```
https:/URL/images/teams/olympique-marseille-890.png
```

Comment: I will correct my question cause I think I mislead you. There are a lot of different URLs coming from the json. I don't have a way to specify a URL for the images.

Comment: @BlitzkriegBlue same mate is here and `\/` is for `json` formatting , the solution will work

Comment: Ohhhh, I get it now. Thanks. xD